# How to get keyboard to move to next textfield

Tags: keyboard, xamarin.ios

I have several UITextFields that are in a group... I need to be able to move from the first to the last, and on the last make it FirstResponder.

I thought the Next key would move the focus, and Done would cause it to become FirstResponder, but apparently not.

Ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to implement the UITextFieldDelegate's ShouldReturn method and in there make the next text field BecomeFirstResponder(). Then return/next will take you to the next field. If return is hit on the last textfield you will call ResignFirstResponder() on that field.

Answer (score 18):

The "Accepted Answer" is right, but I thought a little code wouldn't hurt for people who are new to MonoTouch.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad () {
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    // make first text field have focus
    this.txtMake.BecomeFirstResponder();

    // make 'return' shift focus to next text field
    this.txtMake.ShouldReturn = delegate(UITextField textField) {
        this.txtModel.BecomeFirstResponder ();
        return true;
    };

    // make 'return' on last text field save and close the form
    this.txtModel.ShouldReturn = delegate(UITextField textField) {
        this.txtModel.ResignFirstResponder();
        this.SaveAndClose ();
        return true;
    };
}

private void SaveAndClose() {
    // todo: do something with your data

    // navigate back
    this.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(true);
}
```

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually move the view that contains the text fields, in a way that the text field you want is above the keyboard.

Comment: Dimitris... I don't think you understand my question... it's not a problem with the view... it is that when I tap Next on the keyboard, I want the focus to move to the next textfield... until it gets to the last one, at which point it becomes FirstResponder and the keyboard disappears.